# C# WPF Handling double click events from multiple, dynamically generate datagrids through a single handler

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

In my current implementation, I spawn tabs and grids dynamically.

Basically, a new grid needs to be created by a double click on a any row of a previous grid and use the row data for other provessing.

```
this.AddHandler(DataGrid.MouseDoubleClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler    (Generic_DoubleClick));
```

This handles for any double click even outside the grid and not specifically for the grid.

I need to find a handler which can return the row values specifically to that grid. Please suggest a workaround or a easier way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the double click routed event from datagrid row of the datagrid.

```
   <tk:DataGrid>
        <tk:DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridRow}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                             Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </tk:DataGrid.Resources>
        <tk:DataGrid.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <TextBlock Text="1" Tag="1.1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2" Tag="1.2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="3" Tag="1.3"/>
                <TextBlock Text="4" Tag="1.4"/>
            </x:Array>
        </tk:DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding Text}"/>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag" Binding="{Binding Tag}"/>
        </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </tk:DataGrid>
```

In code behind

```
    private void DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick(
           object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var dgRow = sender as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
        var cellContentElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
    }
```

Bonus is `cellContentElement` is the content element of the cell that was double clicked on the row ... e.g. in case of `DataGridTextColumn` it will be `TextBlock` in the cell.